# iOS MDM configuration profiles and settings keys

Tags: ios, configuration, profile, mdm

I've started to develop a MDM service for iOS devices.
So far I have the enrollment working. And I can send some simple commands (Such as DeviceLock, UnlockDevice, DeviceInformation).
That works fine.

But now I want to install profiles (I guess). I want to set WIFI, APN, et cetera settings.

I've gotten some idea how the mobileconfig plist should look like from the iPhone configuration Utility.

But I haven't found any site with documentation for all the settings.

For one example, how do I set the MMS-APN and the tethering APN?

And also, with the MDM settings command, I can turn on and off DataRoaming, but I can't find any other keys that I can play with. Some suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, there are several key documents:

[Configuration profile reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[MDM documentation](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Documents/mobile_device_management_protocol/mobile_device_management_protocol.pdf)

I believe they describe all publicly available options.

Comment: Thanks. Those two helps. But there are still only 2 Settings documented in the MDM documentation.
Shouldn't there be more settings than dataroaming and voiceroaming?

Comment: As far as public documentation goes, these are only 2 allowed settings. I believe there are some undocumented settings. You can try to look in private ManagedConfiguration framework for them.

Answer (score 1):

The details description about Configuration profiles are is available under [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/).